# Using left and right cosets, show that N must be normal

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $N$ is a subgroup of $G$.Each left coset of N is also a right coset. That is, for each $x \in G$,
there is a $y \in G$ such that $xN=Ny$.Using this prove that N is normal.

I have been working on this, but it seems to be circular with what I try, and I feel like I'm just missing something very basic here.

My attempt is as follows

Take $r\in xN$ such that we have $r=xn$ for some $n \in N$. Similarly we have that $r \in Ny$ such that $r=n_1y$ for some $n_1 \in N$.Thus we have that $xn = n_1y$. Right multiplying by $y^{-1}$ yields $xny^{-1} = n_1$. The requirement to be normal (the one I use from the book I am using requires that for all $x \in G$ we have $xNx^{-1} = N$. What I have is close to what is required, but that $y^{-1} is causing the issue. How do I fix this? or is my process just genuinely wrong? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Closely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283014/a-subgroup-such-that-every-left-coset-is-contained-in-a-right-coset?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cosets partition the group.  And note that $xN\cap Nx\ne\emptyset$.  So if there is $y$ such that $xN=Ny$, we get $Ny=Nx$.  Thus we are done.